# Getting Pytest to run in a Django cookiecutter / Python 3.x project

Tags: django, node-modules, cookiecutter-django

I am building a new [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) project. Here are the [local setup instructions](http://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-locally.html) which I've followed.

When I run "**pytest**" I get the following error 7 times when it tries to collect:

- ERROR collecting node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/MSVSSettings_test.py
- ERROR collecting node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/common_test.py
- ERROR collecting node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/easy_xml_test.py
- ERROR collecting node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input_test.py
- ERROR collecting node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/msvs_test.py
- ERROR collecting node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/ninja_test.py
- ERROR collecting node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/xcode_test.py

  ```
  ../../Envs/kishikoi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:395: in _importtestmodule

  mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)

  ../../Envs/kishikoi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:662: in pyimport

  __import__(modname)

  E     File "/Users/emilepetrone/Sites/kishikoi/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 37

  E       print '%s:%s:%d:%s %s' % (mode.upper(), os.path.basename(ctx[0]),
  E                            ^
  E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  ```

Any ideas? Thank you-

Comment: pytest is trying to load your node_modules directory. The `node-gyp` package [does not support Python 3](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-unix) so you get the error. You could change your [test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html) to exclude `node_modules`.

Comment: @Alasdair that would answer that. Much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pytest is trying to load your node_modules directory. The `node-gyp` package [does not support Python 3](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-unix) so you get the error. You could change your [test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html) to exclude `node_modules`.

The second issue with mailhog looks unrelated. You could try changing the grunt command from `./mailhog` to `/path/to/project/mailhog`. I'm unfamiliar with grunt so I don't know if there's a better solution to change the path.